# Error in WSO2 when writing MongoDB query containing "Aggregate"

Tags: mongodb, aggregate, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-enterprise-integrator

I am working with WSO2 EI 6.5.
I have MongoDB 3.2 installed on my machine.

Whenever I write a Mongodb query containing the operator "aggregate", I get the following error when I call the service " Unknown MongoDB operation 'aggregate' ".

My service needs to link Collections A (id1, fieldA1, fieldA2) and B (id2, fieldB1, fieldB2) for fieldB1 = fieldA2.

Can someone advise?

Thanks.